# How do I find the location of Tomcat's servlet-api.jar?

Tags: tomcat

Previous versions of Tomcat set TOMCAT_HOME and CATALINA_HOME in the environment.

But Tomcat 7 does not set these. I also can't find anything in the registry giving the root Tomcat directory.

How can I programatically get this?

My question is for Windows only.

Comment: Previous versions of Tomcat have also never set them automagically. It's the serveradmin itself who's responsible for that. Perhaps you have used an enhanced 3rd party installer for that, such as XAMPP or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location of JAR file by finding location of any class contained in this JAR, for example using this code:

```
Class<?> clazz = javax.servlet.Servlet.class;
ClassLoader cl = clazz.getClassLoader();
if (cl == null) {
    cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
}
String classLocation = cl.getResource(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class").toString();
String jarLocation = classLocation.substring(0, classLocation.indexOf('!'));
```

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to have the installer add this the my build scripts - when it is not in the classpath. If it is in the classpath then we're ok.